# How to set environment variables within Dockerfile's RUN?

Tags: docker, docker-compose, dockerfile, containers

I need to set the output of a `RUN` command to be an environment variable that is available inside my container after it's built:

```
...

RUN ...
    GO111MODULE=on go get github.com/emersion/hydroxide/cmd/hydroxide && \
    echo "the_password" | hydroxide auth the_username@protonmail.com > bridge_password.txt && \
    BRIDGE_PASSWORD=`sed -n 's/Password: Bridge password: //p' bridge_password.txt` && \
    hydroxide smtp

...
```

Above, I need `$BRIDGE_PASSWORD` to be available in my NodeJS project (`process.env.BRIDGE_PASSWORD`). How can I achieve this?

Comment: Does the password need to be in the container when it is running (i.e. deployed) or only during the image build? I would advise against putting any passwords into a docker image (_it gets committed to an image layer and if you put that into a repo, it will be available for all to see_) and only pass them into the container at run time with the `-e "BRIDGE_PASSWORD=<password>".

Comment: Well I need the `BRIDGE_PASSWORD` to be available from within the container while its running. And the only way to get the password is to run those commands on build or else I would just pass it in.

Answer (score 0):

You need to:

1. Declare your env var with the `ENV` command in your Dockerfile.
2. Substitute your current `RUN` with a command in your image entrypoint so that the variable gets set correctly everytime your start a new container and is available to any launched command.